# Kendo UI for Angular: Can't bind to 'primary' since it isn't a known property of 'button'

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I get this error message:

> Can't bind to 'primary' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.

I am using the `yo aspnetcore-spa` angular generator. `BrowserAnimationsModule` and `ButtonsModule` are imported in my app.module and registered in imports. All my angular and kendo packages are latest versions.

In addition, when I remove `[primary]="true"` from `<button>`, the error goes away. After that, I add `[primary]="true"` again and (without refreshing the page, HMR rebuilds) it works fine. And again, if I refresh the page the error comes back again.

Any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button should look like that:

```
<button kendoButton [primary]="true">Primary</button>
```

Don't forget '**kendoButton**'.

Comment: I have already included kendoButton. Same error. Perhaps it is webpack related?

Comment: The only thing that I have in mind is that you probably have not registered ButtonsModule in app.module.ts or the package is not installed.

Comment: UPDATE: It was Server-side rendering problem.

Answer (score 12):

`Primary` doesnt require brackets around it despite their example saying it does. Try:

`<button kendoButton primary="true">Primary</button>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my test result

A) [primary]="true"

```
<button kendoButton (click)="onButtonClick()" [primary]="true">My Kendo UI Angular Button</button>
```

include css class k-primary and does not include primary attribute

```
<button _ngcontent-ogg-c2="" kendobutton="" ng-reflect-primary="true" class="k-button k-primary" dir="ltr">My Kendo UI Angular Button</button>
```

B) primary="true"

```
<button kendoButton (click)="onButtonClick()" primary="true">My Kendo UI Angular Button</button>
```

include css class k-primary and primary attribute

```
<button _ngcontent-jow-c2="" kendobutton="" primary="true" ng-reflect-primary="true" class="k-button k-primary" dir="ltr">My Kendo UI Angular Button</button>
```

C) [primary]="false"

```
<button kendoButton (click)="onButtonClick()" [primary]="false">My Kendo UI Angular Button</button>
```

does not include css class k-primary and does not include primary attribute

```
<button _ngcontent-oto-c2="" kendobutton="" ng-reflect-primary="false" class="k-button" dir="ltr">My Kendo UI Angular Button</button>
```

D) primary=false

```
<button kendoButton (click)="onButtonClick()" primary="false">My Kendo UI Angular Button</button>
```

include css class k-primary and primary attribute

```
<button _ngcontent-ktx-c2="" kendobutton="" primary="false" ng-reflect-primary="false" class="k-button k-primary" dir="ltr">My Kendo UI Angular Button</button>
```

Conclusion

1. primary in bracket is the correct syntax. It means property binding, i.e. one-way mechanism that lets you set the property of a view element ([reference](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview)). The reason why removing bracket works for some people because modem Web browser will ignore attribute that it does not recognize. ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15038049/418439))
2. Error `Can't bind to 'primary' since it isn't a known property of 'button'` is caused by Kendo UI module is not imported correctly. ([reference](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/troubleshooting/#toc-when-i-try-to-load-a-kendo-ui-component-for-angular-a-runtime-error-occurs-that-the-component-is-not-recognized))

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are importing the ButtonsModule in your module

```
import { ButtonsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ButtonComponent],
  imports: [ButtonsModule],
  exports: [ButtonComponent]
})
```

Comment: This was the error for me.  I needed to add it to the imports for the app.module.