# Results of this css declaration?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What does this CSS declaration do?

```
p, div[aaa="bbb"]{background: #ff0000;}
```

Usually, the selector `[target=_blank]` means that it selects all elements with `target="_blank"`. But, in my question, this means that `aaa` is an attribute which I never saw before. Any help?

Comment: It is a custom one, though as of HTML5 custom attributes needs to be prefixed with `data-*` ... e.g. something like `data-aaa="bbb"`. Here's a good read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute selector in CSS doesn't care about whether or not the attributes being referred to are valid in HTML (which `aaa` isn't).

This selector will match:

```
<p></p>
```

Or

```
<div aaa="bbb"></div>
```

Comment: Small note - aaa is not an invalid attribute – it is custom. The difference between the two is that when the browser parses the HTML standard attributes (e.g. id) are recognized and DOM object properties are created from them.

Comment: Isn't it technically invalid HTML, since it isn't prefixed with `data-`?

Comment: The data prefix makes it standard and creates the DOM object properties on the dataset property.

Comment: Example: <div aaa="bbb" data-a="a" data-b="b" id="myId"></div>

const div = document.querySelector('div');
console.dir(div.id);  // myId
console.dir(div.dataset.a); // a
console.dir(div.dataset.b); // b
console.dir(div.aaa); // undefined

Comment: Invalid would indicate it breaks stuff (like forces quirksmode). You see custom attributes used many places like react, angular and vue.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037149/what-happens-if-an-invalid-nonstandard-html-attribute-is-used-for-data) supports my use of the term "invalid".

Comment: Before the HTML5 doctype I would agree and maybe it's just me being silly about wordings ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for this interesting discussion !