# Passing event elements from input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, events

I wanted to know if theres any other way to pass an element to the function using event,
for example if I have an input:

```
<input name="myname" onChange={onChange}/>
```

then in my onChange function I will see this :

```
onChange=e=>{
console.log(e.target.name)
}
```

and it will print "myname",
I wish to give another value is there a way to do so? for example

```
<input name="myname" othervalue="hi" onChange={onChange}/>
```

and ofcourse:

```
onChange=e=>{
console.log(e.target.name)
console.log(e.target.othervalue)
}
```

thanks in advance!
EDIT: except value because I need it for the onChange form.

Comment: Do you mean *pass in* another value? You can do that with `onChange={e => onChange(e, someOtherValue)}`

Comment: @Jayce444 yes that's exactly what I needed thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
console.log(e.target.othervalue)
```

To:

```
console.log(e.target.getAttribute('othervalue'));
```

You can get the custom attribute value using the method,

> **[e.target.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)**

Answer (score 1):

[Even though it might not represent a big issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037149/what-happens-if-an-invalid-nonstandard-html-attribute-is-used-for-data/15037194), some may say one shouldn't use any arbitrary name for custom HTML attributes.

I suggest that you use the [`dataset` property of any `HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset):

```html
<input name="myname" data-othervalue="hi" onChange={onChange}/>
```

```js
e.target.dataset.othervalue
```