# How do I remove a random HTML attribute added by C# razor engine?

Tags: c#, html, css, razor, blazor

I'm writing a Razor page and noticed that the `C#` razor engine is adding some strange single attribute to many of my HTML tags. For example:

```
<div b-74sq6jd2o7 class="container-fluid">
<a b-74sq6jd2o7 class="fjbhead" href="/"><img b-74sq6jd2o7 src="/assets/logo.svg"></a>
<a b-74sq6jd2o7 class="navbar-brand" href="/Index" style="margin-left:-1em"></a>
```

I did not add "b-74sq6jd2o7" to any of my elements, yet, there it is. It seems to be added to nearly all of my tags. It's not valid HTML either. I tried running my page in debug and production, thinking the compiler only adds it for debug. Nope, it's there all the time.

Furthermore, I spent hours searching for this phenomenon on multiple search engines, I can't find any reference for this.

I'd like to remove this if possible.

Comment: Never seen anything like that. Do you get it if you make a brand new project (no packages, etc) and run it? If not, then it's likely from a package that's on your current project. If you do still get it...Some extension in Visual Studio maybe or in your browser perhaps?

Comment: This project was the default template for a .Net Core ver 6 web app. I didn't add any extensions either. Visual Studio adds some BrowserLink junk, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: "It's not valid HTML either" [yes it is](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes).

Comment: That’s merely syntactically well-formed. Does not make it valid.

Comment: @DStanley That particular link is not particularly on point, saying only that the attribute, if defined, may be defined as a Boolean attribute. [This link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attributes-2) tells us much the same, saying that the value is empty. However, I'm not aware of an attribute named `b-74sq6jd2o7` that is applicable to the `div` element. If it were `data-b-74sq6jd2o7`, that would be fine, but it's not.

Comment: Fair enough - I'm being a bit pedantic. It is valid HTML syntactically, but browsers will ignore it. You can still reference it in CSS (since that's the purpose of adding it) and JavaScript though (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037149/))

Answer (score 6):

That attribute is automatically generated by css isolation

> CSS isolation occurs at build time. Blazor rewrites CSS selectors to
> match markup rendered by the component. The rewritten CSS styles are
> bundled and produced as a static asset. The stylesheet is referenced
> inside the  tag (location of  content). The following
>
> element is added by default to an app created from the Blazor
> project templates, where the placeholder {ASSEMBLY NAME} is the
> project's assembly name

From:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-7.0

You can change it, or disable CSS isolation for a project by setting the `<ScopedCssEnabled>` property to false in the app's project file:

```xml
<ScopedCssEnabled>false</ScopedCssEnabled>
```

Comment: Wow! How did you find that? I have never heard of such a thing. Thank you!

Comment: @jgilmore no problem I've already suffered recently and I lost a lot of time. If it works please don't forget to mark it as correct. If not, please ask here and I will glade to update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't make use of any page-specific stylesheets, you could just delete the empty css files:

_Layout.cshtml.css
Index.cshtml.css
..